# How to get all the ids from all the table rows checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First I create a table with n number of rows and each one of them contains a checkbox. I need to get all the ids from all the row checked.

```
<body>
    <table border='1' style='width:100%'>
            <tr id='1'><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr>
            <tr id='2'><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr>
            <tr id='3'><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr>
            <tr id='4'><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr>
    </table>
<button id='test'>Get Checked</button>
        </body>
```

This is what I got so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#test').click(function(){
var getID = $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').attr('id');
alert(getID);
});
});

</script>
```

But this only gives me one id. If I select many rows I only get the first selected id. Also I need to store all the ids selected in an array for later use.

Comment: first, validate you HTML, table structure is not correct.. all the elements should inside `<td></td>` element

Answer (score 1):

User jQuery's `each` function for this.

```
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function( index ) {
  var closestTr = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  alert(closestTr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, use selector defaults to the first. so , we should use `each` get all selector element.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#test').click(function(){
            var arrId = [];
            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                 var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                 arrId.push(id);
            })
            console.log(arrId);
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var getID = $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').attr('id');
```

Should be:

```
var getID = $('.checkbox:checked').closest('tr').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, demo in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/q6mknzeu/). Make sure adding open td , before each input checkbox

JS

```
$('#test').click(function(){
  var ids = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').prop('id');
      alert(id);
      return id;
  }).get();
  alert(ids);
});
```

HTML

```
<table border='1' style='width:100%'>
  <tr id='1'><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr>
  <tr id='2'><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr>
  <tr id='3'><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr>
  <tr id='4'><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr>
</table>
<button id='test'>Get Checked</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put and id on your table:

```
 <table id="myTab" border='1' style='width:100%'>
```

To avoid getting other checkboxes in the page, select the checkboxes from within the table like:

```
var ids = [];
$('#mytab :checkbox:checked').each(function( index ) {
    var closestTr = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    ids.push(closestTr);
});
alert(ids);
```